# Find an illegal combination of values (composite key) in a table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, composite-key

I need to spot an invalid combination of values within a large data set.
The demo below is a very small data set; however, it illustrates the priniple.
(I use Redshift)

I receive a data set like with 3 columns:
client_id, t_number, t_name.

Client_id, t_number, t_name are repeated many times within the data set (when a clients records a new transaction each of these is recorded as a new line in a file).
t_number (transaction number - (an id of transaction)) and t_name (transaction name) should be an unique combination. A specific t_number should only match to a single t_name (these are duplicated data essentially as number and name should reflect the same activity).

The data set has no null values. There are more t_numbers than t_names.
This suggests that there must be a t_name (set of t_names) with more than one t_number assigned.

The simplified data set is below:

```
create table tmp.test_v1 (
id varchar(5)  
, t_number smallint  
, t_name varchar(5));

Insert into tmp.test_v1 values  
    ('id_1', 1, 'aaa')  
    ,('id_2', 1, 'aaa')  
    ,('id_3', 2, 'bbb')  
    ,('id_4', 3, 'ccc')  
    ,('id_5', 2, 'bbb')  
    ,('id_6', 4, 'ddd')  
    ,('id_3', 5, 'aaa')  
    ,('id_1', 2, 'bbb')  
    ,('id_2', 3, 'ccc')  
    ,('id_4', 4, 'ddd')  
    ,('id_7', 6, 'eee')  
    ,('id_8', 6, 'eee')  
    ,('id_9', 6, 'eee');
```

The t_name 'aaa' is associated with t_number: 1 and 5.
This is a situation that i want to catch.

I came up with a following query:

```
 select t_name, t_number from tmp.test_v1  
    where t_name = (select t_name from (  
    select a.t_name, b.t_number  
    from tmp.test_v1 as a   
    left join tmp.test_v1 as b on a.t_name = b.t_name  
    group by a.t_name, b.t_number  
    order by a.t_name) c  
    group by t_name  
    having count(t_name) > 1)  
    group by t_name, t_number;
```

The above query returns:

```
'---------------------'  
| t_name  | t_number  |  
'---------------------'    
| aaa     |    1      |
'---------------------'   
| aaa     |    5      |        
'---------------------'
```

I can see that t_name 'aaa' has numbers 1,5 assigned to it.

Problem: this does not scale well. On a data set with 130 million records it seems to run endlessly.

What would be a more efficient way to arrive at the same/ similar result?

Comment: I think it is the join that is the problem.  Is it faster if you do https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhwn1WKB7uV2yUZ4FhNPH/0

Comment: Thank you Jerry, your reply solves my problem.  The query you suggested runos on the large data set in a few seconds!

Comment: Not certain how to give you a credit for your reply. 
Maybe you can select 'post your answer' button below the question so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I like to make sure it solves the problem before posting an answer.  And since I had no way to measure "faster" I thought it should be a clarifying comment first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the join is taking all the time.
You can avoid the join and maybe make it faster with:

```
select distinct t_name, t_number from test_v1 where t_name in (
  select t_name
  from ( select distinct t_name, t_number from test_v1 ) t1
  group by t_name
  having count(t_number)>1
)
```

Try it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhwn1WKB7uV2yUZ4FhNPH/0

Answer (score 0):

The joining is cost you all the time.  This is basically a looping condition and with the number of repeated values you have this will explode the data.  Because you want to have both the name and numbers that are violations this makes things a little tricky.  Here's how I'd go after this:

```
select t_name, t_number
from (
  select t_name, t_number, 
      count(t_number) over(partition by t_name) as cnt
  from test_v1
  group by 1, 2 ) sub
where cnt > 1
```

This only scans the table once, doesn't loop join, and drives down the data size quickly through the "group by".

Comment: Thank you Bill, your query works very well on the large data set. I Have not measured the time exactly; running manually it seems to take the same amount of time as query  offered by Jerry.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I think mine will be faster as the data size increases but window functions can be expensive.  If you want the fastest query you will need to drop the requirement that if provide all the t_number values.  Finding just the t_name values that have multiple t_number values would be quicker - "SELECT t_name FROM test_v1 GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(DISTINCT t_number) > 1; ".  However this will only give you the violating t_names only.

Comment: Hi, I timed the queries (each running 'cold' - each run is an initial run as subsequent runs seems to be buffered and returned very quickly):  
1. query by Jerry: 14.901171538978815 seconds
2.query by Bill: 6.417843300849199  
3.short query by Bill ("SELECT t_name FROM test_v1 GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(DISTINCT t_number) > 1;): 7.26141507178545 sec.  

Seems that the query with partions was the fastest. Interesting bit is that the the queryi in point 3 took longer then more demanding query in point two (i cannot guarantee that the  db was free from other traffic)

Comment: Yes, interesting.  There's a break point between DISTINCT and GROUP BY where each is faster.  Likely your data is on the GROUP BY side.  Try this and see if just changing the DISTINCT to GROUP BY has an effect - "select t_name
from (
  select t_name, t_number
  from test_v1
  group by 1, 2 ) sub
group by 1
having count(t_number) > 1;"

Comment: Hi, running "select t_name from ( select t_name, t_number from test_v1 group by 1, 2 ) sub group by 1 having count(t_number) > 1;" today on the full data set took 8.392577567137778 seconds.
Running any other query from this site returns reslults in well less than a second - these must be cashed somewhere.

Comment: There are a few factors to understand when benchmarking queries.  The first time a query runs it is compiled and this takes some time.  Generally people don't want to have compile time in the result to see the execution time so you want to run the query more than once.  But this creates a problem with caching so you need to turn off results caching - "SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF;".  There is also table caching which can skew results so running queries multiple times and in different order can help to remove this effect.